# C# LINQ query children by gender and group by parent gender

Tags: c#, linq

I have to do a query using LINQ of below list.

```
[{
    "name": "Bob",
    "gender": "Male",   
    "children": [{
        "name": "Aron",
        "gender": "Male"
    }, {
        "name": "Jaime",
        "gender": "Female"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Jennifer",
    "gender": "Female", 
    "children": [{
        "name": "Greg",
        "gender": "Male"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "gender": "Male",   
    "children": null
}, {
    "name": "Fred",
    "gender": "Male",   
    "children": [{
        "name": "Tom",
        "gender": "Male"
    }, {
        "name": "Max",
        "gender": "Male"
    }, {
        "name": "Sam",
        "gender": "Female"
    }, {
        "name": "Jim",
        "gender": "Male"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Samantha",
    "gender": "Female", 
    "children": [{
        "name": "Andrew",
        "gender": "Male"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Alice",
    "gender": "Female", 
    "children": [{
        "name": "John",
        "gender": "Male"
    }, {
        "name": "Samantha",
        "gender": "Female"
    }]
}]
```

I need the get parent who has Female children and group it by Parent gender (Like below)

```
[{      
    "gender": "Male",           
        "name": "Jaime",
        "gender": "Female"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Fred",
    "gender": "Male",   
    "children": [{
        "name": "Sam",
        "gender": "Female"
    }]
} , {
    "name": "Alice",
    "gender": "Female", 
    "children": [{
        "name": "Samantha",
        "gender": "Female"
    }]
}]
```

Could you please let me know how I can do it using LINQ

**Edit**

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a list of List of Parent with above json data, hope that makes scene

```
var newlist = parents.where(p=> p.Children !=null && p.Children.Any(c=>     c.Gender=="Female" ))
```

**Edit**
What if you want to have the results as as below

```
[{      
    "gender": "Male",   
     "children": [{        
        "name": "Jaime"       
    }]
},
{    
    "gender": "Female",   
    "children": [{
        "name": "Sam",
        "name": "Samantha",
    }]
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so where are you stuck? *I need the get parent who has Female children*, so you'll need to filter to get only the parents **where** **any** child is female. Then you just **group by** the parent gender.

Comment: can you please use C# code instead of code blocks? We can't linq it without your code since it may  differ how you actually used it

Comment: We need the code, Give us your attempt at a query even..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newlist = 
              Parents
              .Where(p.Children.Any(c=> c.Gender == "Female"))
              .Select(p => p.Parent)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: I haven't tested it but I think that will work for you. I don't think that you need to check for null.. When you select for gender it should null check there